# Windows 7 update will only install Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

I went to update my computer yesterday which currently is running Windows 7 professional.  Every time i go into the Control Panel and to updates though it only shows update to Windows 10 even though it has a list of Windows 7 updates that i wan't to actually install instead of the "upgrade".  I was wondering if there was any way to stop this from coming up?

Answer (score 0):

I too just saw this on my own computer and was really annoyed.  I'm not upgrading to Windows 10 until the last opportunity to do it for free.  It definitely has problems at this time.

Go to the list of optional updates and uncheck the Windows 10 upgrade.  Then it will no longer force you to try and upgrade.